# Cordova Remote Build with Error Code 65

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am trying to build my app for testing using os Sierra within a VM on the same windows 10 PC. I have XCode installed and have my phone setup to deploy from xcode. However, when I try to build the app within VS on windows, I get an error code 65. Here are some screenshots:[VS output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a35iv.png)
[Cordova Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmYR1.png)

Answer (score 0):

it's a certificate problem with your iOS account. You need in XCode to declare some certificate (menu Preferences) !